# Поиск по базе данных с использованием фильтров Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, база-данных, qt

В задании сказанно реализовать приложение, которое будет искать в базе данных элементы по заданным параметрам. Количество параметров и их названия неизвесны. Реализация должна происходить, как на сайтах электронных магазинов - например, ты выбираешь определенные характеристики ноутбука(процессор и видеокарту например) и оно тебе фильтрует по этим характеристикам. Задал еще один параметр - оно отфильтровало те элементы, что уже есть, по новому параметру. Даже алгоритм не могу придумать, как это реализовать, так что заранее спасибо

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter

Comment: @van9petryk спасибо большое за наводку, но не могли бы вы большее подробно обьяснить, как это применить на каком то элементарном примере, а то в документации достаточно скудное обьяснение реализации)

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю считается ли это за ответ . НО хочу рассказать как бы я это решал:

- Во первых : запрос данных с сайта.  для работы с сайтами тебе надо знать их [API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) (программный интерфейс приложения) для запроса их данных (всех видеокарт и процессоров) возможно всей номенклатуры.
- Во вторых: обработка данных это конечно же mysql (здесь проблем нет ибо  в qt интегрирована работа с базами данных mysql)

Если по второму вопросу всё можно решить использую книгу [Qt макса шлее](http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=200373) (и множество других аналогов)

То по первому вопросу происходит множество вопросов . Во первых API каждого сервера свой и имеет отличия (это может быть том-кат , это может быть апач и т.д.). Во вторых эту проблему в своей массе решают с помощью скриптовых языков программирования (Java, Php) даже тот же самый Python используют больше для обработки данных чем для общения с серверами.

---

*Хотелось бы услышать мнение специалистов которые решили такие вопросы на языке C++ c использованием фреймворка Qt.*

*Ибо уже сталкивался с проблемой общения с API сервера но решить её так и не удалось*

Comment: Причем тут вебсайты?

Comment: @mkkik Реализация должна происходить, как на сайтах электронных магазинов

Comment: У автора, судя по вопроcу, просто учебное задание. Нужно создать БД с набором тестовых данных и простенький GUI, позволяющей фильтровать и выводить эти данные. Не нужно обращение ни к каким сайтам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Александр но мы то знаем как быстро проходит школа и начинается взрослая жизнь. А чему либо толковому  научиться можно только на полноценных задачах.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это точно. Просто обычный элементарный интерфейс и две формы на одной из которых происхоид запрос, а на другой непосредственно результат. При изменении параметров на первой форме - меняется вторая.

Comment: @timob256 электронные магазины приводились в пример, потому что там много характристик товара и при выборе любой комбинации из них происходит поиск. Мне нужны просто примеры запросов к базе, так как я понимаю что обычным селектом не отделаюсь

Comment: Мария могу посоветовать книгу макса шлее её в интернете весьма легко найти  **Глава 41. Программирование баз данных** В книге есть примеры, так что просто их переработать по свои интересы.